# JavaScript Math inside function not working

Tags: javascript, function, math, subtraction

The problem I am having is it only returns 10 nothing more or less. Is there is also a better way to do this please share as I am learning and from most of the YouTube videos I have seen they do math outside of a function or math inside the function but only has 1 argument to the string.

```js
var player = {hp:10, at:1};
var enemy ={hp:10, at:1};
function hit() {
    function minus() {
        
        return player.at - enemy.hp;
       }
           console.log(enemy.hp);
           return ;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="hit()">Hit</button>
```

Comment: You are not calling `minus` anywhere. Your whole code is equivalent to `function hit() { console.log(enemy.hp); }`. Functions need to be called in order for the statements in their bodies to be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be what you intended to do.

```js
   
var player = {
  hp: 10,
  at: 1
};
var enemy = {
  hp: 10,
  at: 1
};

function hit() {
  enemy.hp = enemy.hp - player.at;
  console.log(enemy.hp);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="hit()">Hit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Felix Kling said, you're not invoking your function. You're just printing `enemy.hp` to the console.

Here is an example of how you might go about structuring your code:

https://jsfiddle.net/mswilson4040/bg4ey1z9/4/

```
var player = {
  hp: 10,
  at: 1
};
var enemy = {
  hp: 10,
  at: 1
};

function hit() {
  console.log(enemy.hp);
  return minus();
}

function minus() {
  return player.at - enemy.hp;
}
```

Comment: I run the code you posted and the value is still 10 and I was hoping every time you click the hit button the value of enemy.hp would go down 1 and so on

thank you for your time guys